# Horizontal drag motion - How to disable?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave

I've already disabled the **Swipe between pages** option, but I still have this drag jitter...
Can I turn this off?
[image: Drag Jitter]

Edit: It's turned off and not swiping between pages, but I still have this drag motion. Looks like this is a normal macos behavior. Is there any way to change it?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question... The suggested answer didn't solve anything

Comment: Why is still marked as duplicate? It's nothing to do with my question...